# How to create a tabHost containing a ListView?

Tags: android

In the documentation it is said that `TabActivity` is deprecated : [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html). I followed their example using the `FragmentTabHost` but it crashed also. So I tried to create a simple `activity` and adding an `intent` as the content of the `TabSpec`, but the app crashed ! So how to create a `TabHost` containing a `ListView` ?

Here is what I did :

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.onglet_parcelle_batiment);

        mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.onglets);

        mTabHost.setup();

        Bundle dataSent = getIntent().getExtras();

        bien_code = dataSent.getString("bien_code");

        afficherOngletParcelle();

        afficherOngletBatiments();

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    }

    private void afficherOngletParcelle() {

        TabHost.TabSpec parcelle = mTabHost.newTabSpec("parcelle");
        View onglet = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_tab_onglets, null);
        TextView label = (TextView) onglet.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
        label.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.parcelle));
        parcelle.setIndicator(onglet);
        Intent i = new Intent(OngletParcelleListeBatiments.this, ParcelleActivity.class);
        i = i.putExtra("bien_code", bien_code);
        parcelle.setContent(i);
        mTabHost.addTab(parcelle);

    }

    private void afficherOngletBatiments() {

        TabHost.TabSpec batiment = mTabHost.newTabSpec("batiments");
        View onglet = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template_tab_onglets, null);
        TextView label = (TextView) onglet.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
        label.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.titre_liste_batiments));
        batiment.setIndicator(onglet);
        Intent i = new Intent(OngletParcelleListeBatiments.this, ListeBatimentsActivity.class);
        i = i.putExtra("bien_code", bien_code);
        batiment.setContent(i);
        mTabHost.addTab(batiment);

    }
```

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm glad that you asked this question because I have struggled more than 1 day trying to reach what you are trying to reach without using `TabActivity`. But I finally did it. I have made a tutorial for myself and I was about to post it in my blog in the future.

Here is it in details:-

**1)In your XML file, add the following for the 3 tabs.**

```
<TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <!-- tab N°1 --> <!-- Inclusion of the interface -->
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/i_layout_1"
                    layout="@layout/layout_1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                <!-- tab N°2 --> <!-- Inclusion of the interface -->
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/i_layout_2"
                    layout="@layout/layout_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <!-- tab N°3 --> <!-- Inclusion of the interface -->
                <include
                    android:id="@+id/i_layout_3"
                    layout="@layout/layout_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

**2)Create a layout for each tab you are reference in the include components. For example the “layout_1.xml”.**

You can add your `ListView` or anything else here in this layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_textview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Example"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3)Create a custom indicator with the required specifications such as:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/business_tabs_indicator_background"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_indicator_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**4)Create a custom selector for the tab indicator layout to handle the different states of selection, focused,..etc. For example**

business_tabs_indicator_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Active tab -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
<!-- Inactive tab -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
<!-- Pressed tab -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true" />
<!-- Selected tab (using d-pad) -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />

</selector>
```

**5)In your Activity or Fragment, initialize the TabHost and add the corresponding tabs as the following:**

```
 private void initializeTabHoster(View rootview) {
    tabHost = (TabHost) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    //Important
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab Tag");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab Tag");
    TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab Tag");

    // Set the Tab name and Activity
    // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected

    tab1.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("Tab1"));
    tab1.setContent(R.id.i_layout_1);

    tab2.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("Tab2"));
    tab2.setContent(R.id.i_layout_2);

    tab3.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("Tab3"));
    tab3.setContent(R.id.i_layout_3);

    /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3);
}

private View createTabIndicator(String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_indicator_label);
    textView.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

I hope this will help you. Feel free to ask any questions :)

Comment: In the step 3) do I have to create the `custom indicator` ? Is it mandatory ?

Comment: @pheromix No it is not mandatory. But this will allow you to create a custom tab contain an icon with a text, icon only or anything else :). But i**t is not Mandatory**

Comment: Ok , so it is for the tabs on the `TabWidget` ?

Comment: @pheromix It is the top buttons that you have to click on them to select the different layouts

Comment: where in your code do you use the `custom selector` that you created at step 4) ?

Comment: @pheromix I'm using it as a background for the Custom indicator (Step 3)

Comment: I created a shape as the background of my tabs , how can I add the `custom selector` to it ?

Comment: @pheromix Check step (3) using the attribute `android:background` for the container layout